# How to rename a directory in a quilt patch?

Tags: patch, quilt

I want to create a patch using `quilt` in which there is a directory rename. But `quilt add` seems to support just files.

If I should use `quilt add <old_dir>/*` then how can I add the renamed directory to my quilt patch? Invoking `quilt add <new_dir>` before creating it, gives me an error like this (here the `<new_dir>` name is `_include`, the `<old_dir>` name is `include` and the patch name is `0001-fix-cross-compile.patch`:

```
$ quilt add _include/
/usr/share/quilt/scripts/backup-files: line 104: .pc/0001-fix-cross-compile.patch/_include/: Is a directory
Failed to back up file _include/
```

If I use the command without trailing `/`:

```
$ quilt add _include
File _include added to patch 0001-fix-cross-compile.patch
```

Which is not what I mean.

If I first create the directory:

```
$ mkdir _include
$ quilt add _include
cp: omitting directory '_include'
Failed to back up file _include
```

How can I add the new directory to my patch?
Thank you.